# SQL Server's begin tran.. rollback equivalent in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle and I have used the below rollback command in SQL Server. But the same command is not working in Oracle.

```
begin tran  
  ....sql statement
rollback
```

What is the equivalent `begin tran... rollback` in Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle implicitly starts transactions for you whenever you do DML (open transactions are a lot safer in Oracle by default as you don’t have writers blocking readers and you don’t have issues with transaction log backups).

You can end them with either `commit` or `rollback`. There is no need to explicitly start a transaction.

Comment: i am getting error if i use rollback for a select statement

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 1

Comment: We'd have to see that error in context with the _exact_ command(s) that produced it. I'm guessing you did not follow the SELECT statement with a semicolon.   But in general, there is nothing to commit or roll back from a simple SELECT command.  Transactions are started by the execution of DML (INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or DELETE), not SELECT.

Comment: @JSBeginner, are you wanting a read only transaction? See [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SET-TRANSACTION.html#GUID-F11E1E30-5871-48D1-8266-F80A1DF126A1).